# Finding an orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently working on a problem that involves finding an orthogonal basis. It says this:

Consider the matrix A =

```
|1  1|
|1 -1|
|1 -3|
```

So I started out doing this:

B =

```
|1 |       |1|   | 2| 
|-1| - -3/3|1| = | 0|
|-3|       |1|   |-2|
```

I am stuck here. I know the answer is:

```
|1/sqrt(3) 2/sqrt(8)|
|1/sqrt(3) 0        |
|1/sqrt(3) 2/sqrt(8)|
```

How would I get from where I am to the final answer? Do I do another step to the gram schmidt?

Comment: Is the question asking for orthogonal or orthonormal?

Comment: The question states: Find an orthogonal basis of the column space of A.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right answer already. If you are looking for an orthogonal basis, you have correctly applied Gram-Schmidt to get the set
$$
\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}2\\0\\-2\end{matrix}\right)\right\}
$$
Now, comparing this to the answer you say is supposed to be correct: their first vector is the same as yours, except normalized (hence my question about orthonormal). Their second vector I disagree with outright. In fact, it is NOT in the range of the transformation of the matrix. We can check this fact by attempting to solve the system:
$$
\begin{matrix}x+y=\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}}\\x-y=0\\x-3y=\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}}\end{matrix}
$$ 
From the first two equations we get that $x=y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$, but this contradicts the third equation. So the second vector is not even in the range.